Suzuki piano books usage clarification?
I constantly bump into some reference to Suzuki method, for piano there are 7 books. Finally I have to ask :-):

are those books for playing by ear (because this is what Suzuki method is famous about), I mean I listen to recording and then play it back? And the music sheets are just for verification, not actual playing?
should I listen first to the recording, memorize the piece (by ear), and then play by myself or can I play in sync (while listening -- or this is considered "cheating")?

Yes, I know, if I get a proper lesson, the teacher would explain it to me, and so on, but I am curious nevertheless.


are those books for playing by ear (because this is what Suzuki method is famous about), I mean I listen to recording and then play it back? And the music sheets are just for verification, not actual playing?

No and no.

should I listen first to the recording, memorize the piece (by ear), and then play by myself or can I play in sync (while listening -- or this is considered "cheating")?

No.

The design of the Suzuki Method is based on the idea that one can learn music — and musicality — in the same way one learns language: first by imitating the model demonstrated by parents and teachers (watching and listening), and then by developing the formal understanding of language (reading, grammar, etc.).
Early Suzuki lessons involve the teacher showing the student which keys to press, the technique for pressing them, their names (i.e., the alphabet), their rhythm, and their expressive qualities. The student's parent(s) are expected to be directly involved in the lesson in order to repeat the teacher's methods at home. This is supplemented by listening to recordings of the pieces being learned.
The leaps in difficulty from one piece to the next are substantially greater than in other methods, because the teacher and parents are expected to fill in the gaps and explain whatever is necessary to achieve the new piece. The books also lack the instructions found in many other methods, because it is intended to be guided by the teacher.
Although the earliest lessons are by rote and by ear, reading enters the lessons as soon as the student has the maturity to learn to read (e.g., when a child begins to learn language reading in school).
Suzuki teachers go through Suzuki-specific training in order to learn how to use and teach the method.
The Suzuki Method can be very good in helping students develop a sophisticated ear, but that it not its primary intention, and it is specifically designed for use with a teacher. There are other methods geared toward self-learning, and some of those also include ear training.
For more on the Suzuki Method, the starting point is Nurtured By Love, by Shinichi Suzuki, the founder of the method.

Thank you very much for detailed answer. Do I then conclude correctly that those books are simply regular repertoire books for playing with reading the music like from any other repertoire book?

@greenoldman More or less, though especially in Book 1, the teacher frequently teaches the pieces by rote. By Book 2 the pieces are complex enough that reading becomes more necessary.

@greenoldman Furthermore it is my personal experience and opinion that as repertoire books, the Suzuki books are superior to others.

As a Suzuki violin teacher I will say that this explanation of the Suzuki method is really great.
